# Lock rows in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with columns A to F to be filled out by different users. Once one row is completed another user (control user) enteres "done" in column G. As soon as the user entered "done" in coulmn G, I want a VBA script to lock the entire row (column A to G) so that no one can change any of that row entries any longer. Is that possible using VBA scripting?

Comment: Do **all** of *A1* thru *F1* have to be filled?

Answer (score 3):

We must start with all cells *un-protected* and the sheet *Locked*

Enter the following **Event macro** in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim N As Long
    N = Target.Row
    If Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Text <> "Done" Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
      Range("A" & N & ":G" & N).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**