# VBA - How to lock entire column based on a cell value in this column

Tags: excel, vba, locking

I'm sorry this question may look like antoher ones, but I am new in VBA and struggle to get a proper code... 
I would like to protect some data after they were verified. For exemple, I have data in Column B (or whatever column) and I check them in comparaison to manuscrit raw data. I would like to have a cell in that column where I say "Yes" to testify this was checked. After entering "Yes", I would like that all cells in the colum become locked.

I've found a code to lock an entire row ([Lock rows in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451626/lock-rows-in-excel-using-vba)), but whatever i try, i'm not able to modifiy it to work for a variable entire column (only to lock specific column, I'm not able to lock the column where "Yes" is typed ...)

Could someone help me ? 
Thanks !

Comment: You want to 'lock' any column, where you/user has entered "Yes" *anywhere* in that column? Or where "Yes" is entered in a specific cell of that column?

Comment: I would build my sheet to enter "Yes" on only one cell of the column. For exemplt, with have a row labelled "Verified", and we can enter "Yes" in every column of this row; but I would like to lock the entire column where we type "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the code you're looking at there a little and I think it will do what you want. Make sure before you start this that you set all the cells on the sheet to unprotected.

This is set to check row 3 of the sheet for Yes. Change the value on the second line if you need to.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    row_to_check = 3                                                        ' Checking row 3 for "Yes"
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Rows(row_to_check)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    ' exit early if row 3 wasn't changed
    Me.Unprotect                                                            ' unprotect the sheet
        For Each r In Target.EntireColumn.Columns                           ' cycle through each row that has seen a change
              r.Locked = r.Cells(row_to_check, 1).Value = "Yes"             ' set it to protected if the second cell on that row is "Yes"
        Next
    Me.Protect                                                              ' reprotect the sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution can help:

Step 1: select all cells in a sheet. Goto properties (cell format) -> security and deaktivate the checkbox for lock cells (see picture below).

Step 2: protect the sheet with a password. In my example I used "billytalent".

Step 3: copy the following code into the code-area of the sheet. Therefore open the Visual Basic Editor. On the left side you will find a list with your sheets. Double click on the sheet where you want to lock cells with entry "yes". Copy the procedure into the code-area.

```
Private Const PASSW As String = "billytalent"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim cell As Range

   For Each cell In Target
       'only do something, if input is in row 2
       If cell.Row = 2 Then
           'only do something, if someone write yes in a cell
           If cell.Value = "yes" Then

               'deaktivate the protection of the sheet
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=PASSW

               'lock the cells in the column
               ActiveSheet.Columns(cell.Column).Locked = True

               'activate the protection
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=PASSW, userinterfaceonly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
               ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True

           End If
        End If

   Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help, however it only lock the cell where we wrote "yes". Maybe I was unclear in my question !
I would like to lock all the column. Exemple, you type "Yes" in cell A3, then ALL the column A become locked. And it's where I can't find a solution to select all the column to lock :/

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right. English is not my native language. I fixed the code.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help, but it is not exactly that as it lock the entire sheet. I'm not a native speaker either so we may have diffculties o understand each other :p 

I upload an exemple of what my sheet may look like [link](https://ibb.co/L5BY5gG). There you can see Row 2 where we can type "Yes" in different column (C2 or D2 or ...); in order to testify that data enter in "C6:C10" and "C14:C23" ... are verified. After typing "yes" in C2, i would like that only the entire column C is locked; same thing after typing "Yes" in D2; and so on for whatever column of row 2 we type "Yes"

Comment: This look great ! I made some test on my sheet and it effectively locked the column. Thank you very much ! 
And with your comment I guess I will be able to adapt it to other situatio. Thank you !